# MYSQL query/subquery merging

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries below that i'm sure can be combined in to one but i'm not sure how.

I want to get the first_name and email columns for every user, but I also want to get the associated pet_type and pet_breed from the first advert record if they have one.  The advert record only contains a breed_id which is then linked to pet_breeds table to get the pet_type and pet_breed.  I dont need to return the breed_id in the results, just the pet_type and pet_breed.  If no associated advert record exists for a user then I want the pet_breed and pet_type to return the text 'None'.

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.email,
      (SELECT adverts.breed_id AS breed 
      FROM adverts 
      WHERE adverts.user_id = users.user_id 
      LIMIT 1)
FROM users
```

Second Query

```
SELECT pet_type, pet_breed
FROM pet_breeds
WHERE breed_id = breed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` (*to show `NONE` instead of `NULL`*)

```
SELECT  a.first_name, a.email,
        COALESCE(c.pet_type, 'NONE') pet_type,
        COALESCE(c.pet_breed, 'NONE') pet_breed
FROM    users a
        LEFT JOIN adverts b
            ON a.user_ID = b.user_ID
        LEFT JOIN pet_breeds c
            ON b.breed_ID = c.breed_ID
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  a.first_name, a.email,
        COALESCE(c.pet_type, 'NONE') pet_type,
        COALESCE(c.pet_breed, 'NONE') pet_breed
FROM    users a
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT user_ID, max(breed_ID) breed_ID
            FROM adverts
            GROUP BY user_ID
        ) b ON a.user_ID = b.user_ID
        LEFT JOIN pet_breeds c
            ON b.breed_ID = c.breed_ID
```

Comment: ..except it is returning multiple records where more than one adverts record exists.  I only wanted it to return one record per user.

Comment: @user1052096 so you mean any of the records to be shown as long as you have to show atleast 1 pettype and petbreed?